# Getting pixel colours from animated GIF using Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm converting an animated GIF for display on an LED panel. To do this, I need to read the GIF and store the colour value of each pixel in a list.

Using `im.seek(z)` moves to the next frame of animation, but `.getpixel((x, y))` always gets the data from the first frame. How can I get .getpixel to read from the current frame?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

# Open image file
im = Image.open('rgb.gif')

print("\n** Analysing image **\n")

# Display image format, size, colour mode
print("Format:", im.format, "\nWidth:", im.width, "\nHeight:", im.height, "\nMode:", im.mode)

# Check if GIF is animated
frames = im.n_frames
print("Number of frames: " + str(frames))

# Convert to RGB
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

print("\n** Converting image **\n")


# Iterate through frames and pixels, top row first
for z in range(frames):

    # Go to frame
    im.seek(z)
    print("Frame: ", im.tell())

    for y in range(im.width):
        for x in range(im.height):

            # Get RGB values of each pixel
            r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))

            print(r, g, b)
```

Comment: You're invoking `getpixel` on `rgb_im`, which has been initialized before the loop - it never changes inside the loop. It seems to me that, for each iteration of the loop, you'll have to advance `im` to the next frame using `im.seek`, and then update `rgb_im`. Basically move this line: `rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')` into the loop right under `im.seek(z)`.

Comment: Minor note, the width and height have been swapped in the loop, so it will only work for square images.