# Using the first frame of a gif from a url for image processing in the same way as a png?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get the first frame of a gif from a url and use just that first frame for different image processing. Specifically, getting the color of pixels. However, when I try I am getting errors like "'GifImageFile' object is not subscriptable" and "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

The gifs that I will be processing are actually all just one frame and not animated. They were just saved in that format instead of pngs/jpeg for some reason and they seem to be failing where pngs/jpegs succeed. I really just want to be able to process gifs like I am pngs/jpegs and I figured grabbing the first frame would do that.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageStat
from io import BytesIO
import requests

image = requests.get('link.gif', stream=True).content
image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
image.seek(0)

color = image[1,1]
```

Comment: I was able to solve my issue following the logic in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158604/getting-pixel-colours-from-animated-gif-using-python-pil

Answer (score 0):

Given the error `NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, we can infer that `image.seek(0)` returned `None`. I'd go through each line of code like so, in order to make sure everything is doing what I expect:

```
response = requests.get('link.gif', stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()  # did we retrieve the image at all?

bytesio = BytesIO(response.content)
assert bytesio.readable()

image = Image.open(bytesio)
frame = image.seek(0)
assert frame
```

Comment: Well, when I do it with just `image` it says: 'GifImageFile' object is not subscriptable. So I was trying to somehow just use the first frame like a png/jpeg without saving it to disk

Comment: @Cole you'll need to tell us where `image_processing` function comes from, as that's what's throwing the error

Comment: Okay, I will update the OP. But basically I am just trying to get the color of a pixel: `color = image[1,1]`

Comment: @Cole Ive made a terrible mistake - the `seek` func in a FileIO type object moves the pointer, but this `seek` is from the PIL.Image lib which behaves completely differently, so my entire response is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I see. I really am just trying to figure out how to process a gif like I would a png or jpeg file

Comment: Your updated code also returns `None` and seems to be the same thing I was already attempting

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the information I needed in this post: [Getting pixel colours from animated GIF using Python PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158604/getting-pixel-colours-from-animated-gif-using-python-pil)

My updated code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageStat
from io import BytesIO
import requests

image = requests.get('link.gif', stream=True).content
image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
rgb_im = image.convert('RGB')

color = rgb_im.getpixel((1, 1))
```